# Oracle ODBC : Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed

Tags: oracle, excel-2007, oracle9i, citrix

I have message Oracle ODBC : Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed 
when try to open oracle connection in excel.
I'm working in virtual machine via citrix.
Could you please give tips why it is appear and how avoid problem ?

Comment: Here's a blog post that should resolve your issue- http://dbcrusade.blogspot.com/2007/10/oracle-odbc-drivers-sqlallochandle-on.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be a permission issue during the installation of both Oracle 9i and 10G.

If you navigate Oracle home you will find that the directory has different permissions then the root of the tree. In the case of 10G the path is C:Oracleproduct10.1.0Client_1. Open the properties for the Client_X directory, and you will see that "Authenticated Users" should have Read and Execute, List Folder Contents, and Read. To fix the problem, do the following....
-Select Authenticated Users
-Uncheck Read and Execute
-Press Apply
-Check Read and Execute
-Press Apply

Comment: or start process using admin privileges

Answer (score 0):

One item that can cause this error is not having the ORACLE_HOME bin directory in your Windows OS path.
Open a command prompt and type either PATH or SET to see if the directory is included. Adjust as required.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to resolve the issue:

1. Select Administration Tools , Local Security Setting and Local Policy.
2. Then select "User Rights Assignment"
3. Double click on "Create Global Objects"
4. Select Add User or Group.
5. Make sure Object Types Group Box is checked.
6. Select Locations and highlight the name of the server you are working on (Not the Domain).
7. Enter "Remote Desktop Users" or "Everyone" (without the quotes) into the Object Names Box.
8. Select OK.
9. Add the same users to the group "Power User".
10. If this does not work, after step 8 a reboot may be required.