# Error creating connection to Oracle ODBC in Excel

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

I am trying to connect to Oracle ODBC for OraClient10g_home1 in System DSN.once done,i have tested the connection and it says connection successful.but when i try to import Oracle data from Excel's built-in function (Microsoft Query),it gives me the following error message.please let me know how to fix this issue.

**Oracle Database Server - 32 Bit,Operating System - Windows 10(64-Bit),Excel Office 2010 (32-Bit)**

[image: error]

Comment: please check your entry in tnsnames.ora file location in ORACLE_HOME/network/admin path. correct this and in windows cmd using tnsping check its status (tnsping yourentry) if this works odbc also will work

Comment: thanks for the reply.tried doing tnsping like this on cmd tnsping D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\network\admin and it displays this : TNS-03505: failed to resolve name

Comment: did you  check tnsnames.ora file in D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\network\admin. is there your entry in tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: what entry are you talking about actually?i did check tnsnames.ora file and tried this on cmd tnsping 172.16.1.23 which is being the host and the reply is OK(0 msec)

Comment: I assume your Excel is 32 bit. Did you create the DSN also in the 32 bit ODBC Administrator? Otherwise it does not work.

Comment: Yes i created the DSN.tested the connection.successful it says but still no luck.the error message persists.there must be something silly i am not being able to find

Answer (score 0):

in `tnsnames.ora` you should have an entry for database instance located in target server like :

```
Test=
 (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=target server)(PORT=1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = orcl)
    )
  )
```

then `tnsping Test` in `cmd` should work fine. you will use this `tns` entry in your odbc.

Comment: i have all of the entries you have said in the above post but it still does not work.

Comment: now its showing me this error : **SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed**

Comment: sorry for delay. please check  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626024/oracle-odbc-drivers-sqlallochandle-on-sql-handle-env-failed"