# Error accessing Oracle view through SSIS

Tags: ssis, oracle12c

I'm getting errors while trying to access an Oracle view through an SSIS package. First, since, I'm running 64-bit windows, I installed the 64-bit Oracle 12c Client. But when I tested the connection I got this error:

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

Then I tried installing the 32-bit Oracle 12c Client but got another, different error.

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Lastly I tried installing both clients together but the last error persisted. Not sure what's going on here...

Answer (score 1):

The first error comes from the fact that Visual studio is 32 bit and it's trying to use 32 bit drivers by default. You can change the runtime settings like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28235255/5605866

The second error might refer to tnsnames.ora file not having all the settings correctly, like in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40399744/5605866