# Access Oracle Database from Excel: Error with ODBC

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

I'm trying to import data from Oracle to Excel. I was hoping to find Oracle DB on the drop down under Get Data as see online:

[image]

That picture not being there I hit the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-an-oracle-database-power-query-d7fbd231-a705-4eb7-83b3-a66bfb678395) explaining I should install **32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.2.4)**.

After doing this, I could not see the drop down. However, I read [elsewhere](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9525905800346989316) that it could be accessed from the Other Sources > From OBDC:

[image]

I went through my Windows Admin Tools > ODBC Data Source Administrator and there I added a new Microsoft ODBC for Oracle Setup.

My database now appeared in the ODBC database choice drop down. I call for the query and... I get two errors:

First a Windows error:

> "The Oracle(tm) client and networking components were not found.
>   Thesec components are supplied by Oracle Corportation and are part of
>   the Oracle Version 7.3 (or greater) client software installation. You
>   will be unable to use these drivers until these components have been
>   installed"

Then power query error:

> "ODBC: ERROR [IM004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's
>   SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed"

So now I'm a litte confused and don't understand what this means and what I've done wrong. Other posts here didn't point to the right direction (I think).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626024/oracle-odbc-drivers-sqlallochandle-on-sql-handle-env-failed ?

Comment: Is your Excel also 32-bit? You can just install the **Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)** - Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio are not required.

Comment: Which ODBC Data Source Administrator did you open? Be aware there is an 32-bit version (`c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`) and a 64-bit version (`c:\Windows\odbcad32.exe`). By default you will start the 64-bit version which might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys. Excel 32 bit and used ODBC 32 bits as well. I installed ODAC and ticked off the Visual Studio bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to connect to the Oracle database.

1. I had to install some pre-requisites, namely the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable packages x_64 and x_86.
2. I followed the steps in this document: https://manjaro.site/how-to-install-oracle-odbc-driver-on-windows-10/

It worked like a charm and I also can connect to MySql as bonus.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the Oracle Home (the path where the 32-bit Oracle Data Access Components is installed) to your PATH systemvariable. You need an entry for the oracle_home and oracle_home\bin, i.e. your installation path is c:\oracle\client12 then add `PATH=c:\oracle\client12;c:\oracle\client12\bin;c:\windows\system32....` to the path variable. In most cases the pc needs a reboot after the path was changed.

You add an ODBC-DSN with the driver "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle". This odbc driver is deprecated. You should use the native oracle driver named "Oracle in ...."  in the odbc dialog. [image]

The used Oracle Home needs a tnsnames.ora file (or other tns resolve method like onames, ip) to resolve the tnsalias to a database service or sid. The file is located in your Oracle Home path in the subdirectory `network\admin`. Example tnsnames.ora:

```
orcl.example.com =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myserver.example.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

The tnsalias `orcl.example.com` is resolved to `myserver.example.com` with listner port `1521`. The connected database service is `orcl`.

This tnsalias is used for the definition of the ODBC DataSourceName:
[image]

If the drop down box has no values you can overwrite the box with your defined tnsalias. In the example orcl.example.com

Comment: Thanks! I've tried using these, however there's no TNS Service Name listed. I've then found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437522/odbc-administrator-cant-find-oracle-tns-names-file but I'm not sure of the answer. How can it connect to a database without having a host url or ip provided?

Comment: This was close to being the answer. I had some missing pieces and the ora file pointing to the TNS wasn't were it was supposed to be so I couldn't get it right.